# How to prevent Google Chrome from blocking my installer package

Tags: google-chrome, download, installation, wix

I've prepared and published on my website an installer package with the software I developed. The package is compiled and bundled into .exe file using WiX toolset and contains no viruses or malware. Next when I try to download the file I get a notification from Chrome that it's blocked due to malicious content.
[Malicious content warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VxNbK.jpg)

I'm really upset that my customers being misinformed with such warning. Any ideas how to get around it?

Comment: Read this: http://blog.chromium.org/2012/01/all-about-safe-browsing.html

Comment: Sadly, it doesn't help. There's no clue how to gain reputation for my downloads

Answer (score 2):

Google created this page for developers - https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249.

Even though it doesn't say it on there, almost all auto-detection software will not block software that is digitally signed (and there is no bad reputation associated with the signing certificate).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple file, just upload it to Google Drive or DropBox, and generate a public link for it and then share it on your website.

You can also shorten that link, if your application provide this service, or via `goo.gl`, in order to view clicks' count.

---

If any developer come across this issue, I manage to resolve it by streaming the downloadable file instead, via different URL (which doesn't have the file name and its extension with file's full path on your hosting).

Doing so by manipulating the response header, will fix the issue.

Here is a useful [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26784775/3317006) about streaming a downloadable via php script