# Downloads over 2MB on Azure Linux Web App (PHP 7.4) fail

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, apache2

We are trying to migrate our website from smaller provider to Azure, everything went smooth except that we are unable to download files that have more then 2MB when trying to do that we are getting error 400.

Already tried multiple solution for example:
https://azureossd.github.io/2020/09/15/unable-to-download-static-content-php-on-azure-app-service-linux/index.html
playing with php.ini, testing in any other Azure Linux container is giving the same output, there are no logs about that on Azure.

Here's portion of code that we are using for testing:

```
$file = "test.exe";
$quoted = sprintf('"%s"', addcslashes(basename($file), '"\\'));
$size   = filesize($file);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/*');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=' . $quoted); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . $size);    

readfile($file);
```

I compared php and apache settings from the old server and they are practically the same, what am I missing here?

Comment: we can provide php config values for next options
- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size

Comment: Did you try to stream the file instead of buffering it whole? [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914912/streaming-a-large-file-using-php) can help

Comment: @MykhailoYATSYSHYN upload_max_filesize = 20M
post_max_size = 4096M
update: I changed upload_max_filesize to 4096M same as on old server, still same issue

Comment: So that I understand you correctly, do you want to upload a file to the server or give the file from the server?

Comment: Download the file from the server

Comment: @Marcin What does the error log say? we can guess for a long time, a specific error should hit in the log

Comment: Turned out it is Azure bug - confirmed by Microsoft support.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new ini file: /home/site/ini/my.ini with the following contents:

> ```
> upload_max_filesize = 150M  
> post_max_size = 100M
> ```

2. Use PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR AppSetting to let the system use your additional ini config, with below value :
   /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d:/home/site/ini